# How to filter duplicate items with the lowest value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects shown below, I need to remove all the duplicate items with the lowest price values, e.g the item 'Book' with price '8' should be removed because it is the lowest book price, how can I go about doing that?

```
let array = [
      {
        item: "Pen",
        price: 3
      },
      {
        item: "Book",
        price: 10
      },
      {
        item: "Pen",
        price: 6
      },
      {
        item: "Book",
        price: 8
      }
    ];
```

Comment: effort so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the items to object. For each item, if it doesn't already exists in the object, or it's price is higher than the current item of the same type in the object, add it to the object using the `item` property as key. Convert back to an array using `Object.values()`:

```js
const array = [{"item":"Pen","price":3},{"item":"Book","price":10},{"item":"Pen","price":6},{"item":"Book","price":8}]

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(!r[o.item] || o.price > r[o.item].price) r[o.item] = o

  return r
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array = [{
    item: "Pen",
    price: 3
  },
  {
    item: "Book",
    price: 10
  },
  {
    item: "Pen",
    price: 6
  },
  {
    item: "Book",
    price: 8
  }
];

// remove dups
let grouped = array.reduce(function(all, next) {
  if (all[next.item]) {
    all[next.item].push(next.price)
  } else {
    all[next.item] = [next.price]
  }
  return all
}, {})

// remove smallest values
let result = Object.keys(grouped).map(function(key) {
  return {
    item: key,
    price: Math.max.apply(null, grouped[key])
  }
})

console.log(result)
```